# Display thumbnail of page when displayed in website search results

Tags: c#, solr, sitecore, thumbnails, computed-field

Our client wants to display a thumbnail of a screenshot of a page when listed in the search results of the website. Of course, they want it to be automated. The website is build on Sitecore 9.0 and uses SOLR for indexing. It seems that creating a computed index field would be the best option performance-wise, but I feel like it will still take forever when running a full index rebuild as it's making an http request for every page.

I took a look at some solutions for capturing thumbnails, this one looks to be the most promising http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/. However, it doesn't seem like this will work with server-side C# http requests. Also, not sure how I'd selectively toggle the html2canvas event on pages as well as have the page send back the image as a response in the http request.

Any other solution ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how sitecore works exactly, but most cms allow to 1. add thumbnails to content or create an arbitrary field you can use for that purpose, 2. add fields to the search index, 3. manage how to render search results using specific template(s). So the best option imho would be to have thumbnails created during content creation, either directly by authors or automatically (server side), and let their path/url be _stored_ in Solr so that you can retrieve them with search results and display them with a simple `<img src="@url">` tag in the dedicated template.

Comment: @EricLavault The client wants the process to be automated. Meaning when a page is created or updated in the CMS, the corresponding thumbnail would get created/updated automatically. I'm looking for a service that provides the ability to parse a page's markup and return an image. In order for it to be automated, it would have to be triggered and called upon server side.